# Consume a WebSocket connection using Scala and Play

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for a way to consume a websocket in Scala.

The websocket is created in a play Application. Here the code in the

**controller**

```
def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, JsValue] { request => out =>
  WebsocketActor.props(out)
}
```

**routes**

```
# Sockets
GET     /socket                          controllers.MyController.socket
```

Connecting to the socket using Javascript works fine.
Now I want to connect to the socket using a http-Client. At the moment I use the PlayHttpClient

**Client sbt dependecy**

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.3.4"
```

**Code to consume Websocket**

I found several methods on the client that might do the trick but I'm lost which one to use and how to use them:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequestHolder

```
def get[A](consumer: (WSResponseHeaders) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]]
```

looks like it could do the trick. But how to Implement a Consumer?

```
def getStream(): Future[(WSResponseHeaders, Enumerator[Array[Byte]])]

// Thats how I used it
  def alertStream = client.
    url(http://localhost:9000/socket).
    withHeaders("Accept" -> "application/json").
    stream.map { case (headers, enumerator) =>
      println(headers)

      val loggingIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { chunk =>
        val chunkString = new String(chunk, "UTF-8")
        println(chunkString)
      }

     enumerator.apply( loggingIteratee )

loggingIteratee.run
```

}

I tried this one but I get an 400 - Excpetion in the ResponseHeaders all the time. Changing the protocol to ws:// in the url leads to this exeption:

```
> val con = client.url("ws://localhost:9000/socket").get
java.io.IOException: WebSocket method must be a GET
at    com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:989)
```

Comment: I'm down the same track, and I think the trouble is that the WS library simply does not support connecting to WebSockets yet.

Comment: Hope to hear of you, when you found a sloution. Would be sad if the feature really is missing.

Comment: Play WS doesn't support web sockets. Have you considered something like: https://github.com/backchatio/hookup

Comment: @AndreasNeumann...any solution for the issue above ?

Comment: nothing yet. The only thing I found to work was: Consume websocket with Selenium in scala test  http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium then map the javascript code back to scala.