# Implementing a WebSocketClient in Scala controller

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.4

I have a scala controller in which I am calling an external webservice using `WS` api of Play! framework which returns a json. The same api is now to be called using a WebSocketClient as every connection should be made using a WebSocket instead of `http`. So normal `Action` in controller are converted to `WebSocket` functions, however I am not being able to call a `WebSocket` function from within the scala code. I have searched and gone through several places on web for the solution, but I didn't found the solution anywhere. How can this be done, calling a WebSocket function and fetch its json using a WebSocketClient in scala code OR we can say, consuming a `WebSocket` from within scala code ? I found a similar to mine questio on SO but none has given an answer to that! I want to know whether its possible or not in Play framework ?

[Consume a WebSocket connection using Scala and Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929536/consume-a-websocket-connection-using-scala-and-play)

Edit: I am implementing the following code:

```
val c = new AsyncHttpClient()
val webSocketClient = c.prepareGet("ws://0.0.0.0:9000/testSocket").execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().addWebSocketListener(new WebSocketTextListener {

  override def onMessage(s: String): Unit = {
  }

  override def onOpen(webSocket: websocket.WebSocket): Unit = {
    webSocket.sendTextMessage("test")
  }

  override def onFragment(s: String, b: Boolean): Unit = {}

  override def onError(throwable: Throwable): Unit = {}

  override def onClose(webSocket: websocket.WebSocket): Unit = {
    latch.countDown()
  }
}).build()).get()

val result = webSocketClient.sendTextMessage("true")
println("================================" + result)
```

The `result` variable is not printed on console giving a json parser exception.

Update: My `WebSocket` connection in `ws://0.0.0.0:9000/testSocket` which is inside a scala controller of different project, is as under:

```
def sockeTest = WebSocket.tryAccept[JsValue] { request =>
  futureJsonVariable.map { json =>
    val in = Iteratee.ignore[JsValue]
    // Some database computation here which generated a Future[JsValue] value in futureJsonVariable variable.
    val out = Enumerator(json).andThen(Enumerator.eof)
    Right((in, out))
  } recover {
    case err => Left(InternalServerError(err.getMessage))
  }
}
```

Update2: One last thing I would like to ask regarding this is that, we invoke a `WebSocket` connection using `webSocket.sendMessage("test".getBytes())` which gives us the response of `WebSocket` in the overridden method `onMessage()`. I want to know, how can we await until a `WebSocket` response is being received, so that we can perform the required computations with the `WebSocket` response data. I have checked by returning a `Future[JsValue]` variable inside the `onMessage()` method but that thing is something invalid. So how can we put `webSocket.sendMessage("test".getBytes())` in await mode, so that further code is executed upon the response of `WebSocket` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play doesn't support WebSocket client connections.  The best option is probably to use `AsyncHttpClient`, this is the library that Play's WS API is built on so it will already be on your classpath, instructions for accessing WebSockets using it are here:

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Comment: thanks for your reply, I gone through the github link provided by you and I can see the code implementation is in java. Will try implementing the same code in scala as I am working with scala controller. Do you have any link reference in your knowledge base where this same implementation is provided in scala ?

Comment: I suggest you learn Scala better. Java code can trivially be converted to Scala code.

Comment: I tried implementing the scala code out of the java code provided at your said github link. I want to know like, how should I retrieve the json output when a WebSocket is connected from scala(A WebSocket is connected when we perform `webSocketVar.sendTextMessage("test")` ? I want to know what should I write inside the overridden method `onMessage()` so as to get the json response of the WebSocket method I am connecting? I have updated in my question for the code I am implementing.

Comment: @VinitSharma Why don't you just use the Java library? Scala is capable of interop with Java. Using a well tested library is better than doing all of that work on your own.

Comment: @bash0r, I am quite new with Play! framework and scala language. Frankly speaking but I didn't get what you are trying to say. I have simply implemented the code in scala taking help of the java code provided on the git link given by JamesRoper. Am I implementing the code in a wrong way ? Or am I missing for something in my code above ? Please help regarding this.

Comment: @VinitSharma You can use the Java code as is. Both languages compile down to the JVM (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine). So you don't need to implement it on your own. Then there would be a question: Do you use a build system?

Comment: @bash0r, I am using Intellij IDEA SBT plugin for build purpose. Even though I use the same java code, but still I don't know how would I be able to fetch the json response by calling the `WebSocket` function in scala code ? Any idea about it ?

Comment: @VinitSharma Have a look at this specific file: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/ws/WebSocketTextListener.java

It implements a Java interface, which are used in Java for Lambdas and Callbacks and such things. You can create a `new WebSocketTextListener { }` just right in place with the method `WebSocket addWebSocketListener(WebSocketListener l);` to apply the listener to a WebSocket. That's not the Scala way of handling this kind of problems, but it works. :)

Comment: @bash0r, If you take a look at my code, I have done the same thing in scala which you are telling me to do, but I need to override the `onMessage()` method in such a way, so that I can get the json response of the `WebSocket` by calling the `sendTextMessage` method.

Comment: @VinitSharma The parameter `s` of type `String` holds that value. You need to convert it with a JSON parser to Scala objects. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591457/scala-2-10-json-serialization-and-deserialization` is what you're looking for I guess.

Comment: @bash0r, I understood what you are saying, but still am helpless and don't know what to write inside the `onMessage(s: String)` method, also one more thing that, how do I connect the `WebSocket`, because simply calling the `sendTextMessage("test")` didn't initiated the `WebSocket` connection ? Any small amount of code as a hint would also suffice.

Comment: @VinitSharma That's what I've found with help of Google: https://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/writing-websocket-clients-using-asynchttpclient/

Comment: @JamesRoper, Sir I have added my code implementation in the question. Can you please suggest me for  what is being missing in my code ? I need to fetch json by calling a WebSocket connection from my scala code. How would I achieve that ?

Comment: Got resolved my issue. My `WebSocket` connection was created to accept and provide value of type `JsValue`, while I was trying to connect the `WebSocket` by sending a string message, because of which it was not getting connected. By using `sendMessage()` instead of `sendTextMessage()` solved my issue and I can connect the `WebSocket` now and fetch its json value as well. Cheers to @JamesRoper for telling me the right thing to implement.